# Error: could not find function "chooseCRANmirror"

Tags: r, cran

I use R on via the terminal on macOS Catalina. I had run into issues installing libraries, e.g.

```
> install.packages("caret")
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘caret’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)
```

This issue can be solved by:

```
chooseCRANmirror(12)
```

I added that line to my `~/.Rprofile` so that it auto-loads it at the start of every session. However, that returns:

> Error: could not find function "chooseCRANmirror" [Previously saved
> workspace restored]

, and doesn't load the R profile, even though it works when I put it directly into my console. Why is this? And is there a solution to auto chooseCRANmirror(12) without having to manually do it each session?

Here is the rest of my `~/.Rprofile`:

```
local({r <- getOption("repos")
      r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com"
      options(repos=r)})
chooseCRANmirror(12)

options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 
options(max.print=100)
 
options(scipen=10)
 
options(editor="vim")
 
# options(show.signif.stars=FALSE)
 
options(menu.graphics=FALSE)
 
options(prompt="> ")
options(continue="... ")
 
options(width = 80)
 
q <- function (save="no", ...) {
  quit(save=save, ...)
}
 
utils::rc.settings(ipck=TRUE)
 
.First <- function(){
  if(interactive()){
    library(utils)
    timestamp(,prefix=paste("##------ [",getwd(),"] ",sep=""))
 
  }
}
 
.Last <- function(){
  if(interactive()){
    hist_file <- Sys.getenv("R_HISTFILE")
    if(hist_file=="") hist_file <- "~/.RHistory"
    savehistory(hist_file)
  }
}
 
if(Sys.getenv("TERM") == "xterm-256color")
  library("colorout")
 
sshhh <- function(a.package){
  suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(
    library(a.package, character.only=TRUE)))
}
 
auto.loads = c("viridis", "tidyverse", "data.table")
 
if(interactive()){
  invisible(sapply(auto.loads, sshhh))
}
 
.env <- new.env()
attach(.env)
 
.env$unrowname <- function(x) {
  rownames(x) <- NULL
  x
}
 
.env$unfactor <- function(df){
  id <- sapply(df, is.factor)
  df[id] <- lapply(df[id], as.character)
  df
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the package.

```
utils::chooseCRANmirror(12)
```

`.Rprofile` only loads the base package. See [`?Startup`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html).

> Note that when the site and user profile files are sourced only the base package is loaded, so objects in other packages need to be referred to by e.g. utils::dump.frames or after explicitly loading the package concerned.